# What do you call the list of required parts used to build a machine/robot?

Tags: word-request

In my example, there's multiple machines each with their own list of required parts to build them.

Is there a name or term for them like a recipe for machine or something?

Comment: What's wrong with 'list of required parts'?

Comment: "Essentials"? ..

Comment: I'm making an app that support this functionality, and trying to fit  'list of required parts' into a small button so it would fit in the main menu doesn't work well. Was hoping there's a better term for it.

Comment: "What you'll need" is common. Or, "Required". I suggest you incorporate your comment into your post, so that everyone is aware of the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bill of Materials is defined in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bill-of-materials) as

> noun
>
> plural **bills of materials** (written abbreviation **BOM**)
>
> ***a document showing a list of all the materials and parts that are needed to produce something:***
>
> The most expensive piece in the product's bill of materials is the touch-sensitive display.

BOM is an expression often used in industry, but may not be understood by all users of the app mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Looks like Jack beat me to the post by a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A common term is "bill of materials", which is sometimes abbreviated BOM:

[Wikipedia "Bill of Materials"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials)

"A bill of materials or product structure (sometimes bill of material, BOM or associated list) is a list of..."